# Python order of evaluation for a logging instantiation. Why do imported modules get evaluated first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

Hi I have kind of an advanced question.  I'm basically having a hard time why a downstream class has a class attribute log object being instantiated first. I have a python application with about 20 classes and 3 different modules and the application does some logging.  I want to make the logging path configurable from the cli but at first, I just hard coded the logging path and instantiated a logging object.  Then that logging instance to all other parts of the application with the hard coded path.  So I hard coded logging path at first (just `app.log`). Now I'm trying to allow the user to set the path of the logging.  So in my `Log` class, I have a singleton-esque method `set_handler` that sets the handler, which is a class variable. It follows a singleton pattern in that it can be just set once. So the user will pass in a logging path as well for the "first" handler.  If the handler is already set for later log instantiations, then no handler is configured, the same handler is used, just a new log object is returned. So if the user passes in `xyz.log` then it will be set forever, fine.  But it seems I cant nail down when the *first* time actually it is called.  The entry point is much different than the first time a logging object is being instantiated.  Im trying to force the log instantiation but python keeps having the first instantiation as something different. Its actually a class that is being imported by an imported class that is imported by the class that I actually want to execute first.  And that class (which the code doesn't hit until much later) has a log object which is being instantiated first.  So that class's log object is being instantiated but the user provided log path has not been passed yet, which is my intent.  So basically Im not able to force python to evaluate the proper log instantiation first.

Comment: This may not answer your question directly, but something that is not obvious, at least it wasn't to me, is that the *first* module that does `import logging` gets to call the shots. That might be in a module of yours, or it might be in something else that your module imports (any number of levels down). To be sure of being in control of the log instantiation,  do it in a very early import by your main program. Even if the linter says that import should be lower down.

Comment: Oh thats great to know and thanks for adding that. The class that is doing the instantiation first is actually just importing `os`, `subprocess` and three other first-party classes including the `Log` wrapper class.

Comment: It seems only the class variables get evaluated first. If I add a singleton pattern to those as well, then it continues on.  But its a crap design

Comment: The logging package will be imported the first time the Python interpreter encounters the statement `import logging`.  At that point it will not be "configured", so nothing will get logged.  It is only when you call one of the logging packages's configuration functions that logging begins.  You say that the user "passes in" the path of the log file (I think that's what you mean) - does this happen on the command line?  In that case, you can't configure logging until your code parses the command line (obviously) so if you need to log something meantime, you have to send it somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah I was collecting a list of messages while the user input was being parsed.  Actually what happened was here https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/20/python-class-attributes-are-evaluated-on-declaration.html.  I was storing the logger as a class attribute and when I imported the class, it was evaluating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was happening was basically here, the logging object was being evaluated as soon as the class of the class attribute was imported. (When `Class2` was imported, it's class attribute `log` was evaluated and thus instantiated). This guy did a blog about it - https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/20/python-class-attributes-are-evaluated-on-declaration.html.  So to lay it out in more detail I had one file like

```py
import other_stuff   
 
from module2 import Class2 

class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
            do stuff 
    
    def func1():
        do stuff with Class2
```

And then in module 2 it looked like

```py
import os 
import subprocess 

import other_stuff 

class Class2:
    log = LoggerClass(log_path=__name__)
      
    def __init__(self):

    def func2():
        do stuff
```

And in the application entry point it was like so.  This was the part that I wanted to evaluate first... but it did not evaluate first.

```py
import click 
import other_stuff 

from module1 import Class1

@click.command("start")
@click.option(--logpath)
def start(logpath):
    log = LoggerClass(log_path=__name__)
```

I was thinking that the `log` object in the `start` function in the entry point would be the first instantiated but it was the `log` object that was a class attribute of `Class2` that was instantiated first actually.  This is because a class's class attributes are evaluated upon being imported. Like when you import a class, that causes all the class attributes to be evaluated.

So I actually just changed the code in Class2 to be like

```py
import os 
import subprocess 

import other_stuff 

class Class2:
    log = None
      
    def __init__(self):

    def func2():
        do stuff 

    @classmethod
    def log(cls):
        if cls.log is None:
             cls.log = LoggerClass(log_name=__name__)
        return cls.log
```

And then of course I change the statements that do the logging from `Class2.log.logstuff()` to `Class2.log().logstuff()`. So the calls to log stuff no longer reference the class attribute `log` and instead call the class method `log()`.